# Resolving Facebook Sharing Crash Issue on iOS 12 and Earlier

Tags: ios, sdk, fbsdksharedialog

Following the upgrade of our game to the latest Facebook API version, we encountered a problem during testing. Users who have iOS 12 or earlier operating systems are experiencing crashes when attempting to use the sharing feature after updating the game. We are seeking assistance in finding a solution for this issue.

Facebook SDK Version: 13.0.0
Device: iPhone 6, running iOS 12

We have tried resetting the phone and reinstalling the application.